# how to open (after clicking) react component in new page

Tags: reactjs

Hi every one I am trying create new page in react in this way.
I Have component which name is   "SolutionsSectionsPic".
And I want after clicking on that component open another  component (which name is "SItem" ) in new page (not in new tab). I am writing something like this

```
    <Router>
        <Link to="/ecommerce">
          <SolutionsSectionsPic />
        </Link>
        <Route path="/ecommerce" component={SItem} />
    </Router>
```

But when I click on  "SolutionsSectionsPic" component, my "SItem" component immediately appears under "SolutionsSectionsPic" component.
How can I fix it?

Comment: post the code of `SItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `Link` will always be rendered no matter what. A solution to this is wapping your `Link` in a `Route`, that way it will only be rendered on that route.

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" exact>
     <Link to="/ecommerce">
       <SolutionsSectionsPic />
     </Link>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/ecommerce" exact component={SItem} />
</Router>
```

You also see that I use `exact`, that means that only / will be valid, otherwise all routes that start with / will be valid.

Comment: Nothing was changed :/

Comment: Did you use exact? Please update your code in your question. @vrto95 I fixed an issue in my code, please try again.